# How to loop inside a td in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, ngfor

Hi I have a data structure as below:

{

```
"status": {
    "code": null,
    "message": null,
    "status": 200,
    "parameters": null
},
"response": {
    "id": 63,
    "years": [{
        "year": 2018
    }, {
        "year": 2017
    }],
    "createdBy": "System",
    "createdOn": 1528448882000,
    "modifiedBy": "System",
    "modifiedOn": 1528448882000,
    "uploaded": [{
            "id": 97,
            "createdBy": "System",
            "createdOn": 1528448883000,
            "modifiedBy": "System",
            "modifiedOn": 1528448883000,
            "year": 2017,
            "fileName": "file2.pdf"
        {
            "id": 97,
            "createdBy": "System",
            "createdOn": 1528448883000,
            "modifiedBy": "System",
            "modifiedOn": 1528448883000,
            "year": 2017,
            "fileName": null,
        },
        {
            "id": 97,
            "createdBy": "System",
            "createdOn": 1528448883000,
            "modifiedBy": "System",
            "modifiedOn": 1528448883000,
            "year": 2018,
            "fileName": file4.pdf,
        }
    ],
    "uploadedFromTS": [{
        "id": 97,
        "createdBy": "System",
        "createdOn": 1528448883000,
        "modifiedBy": "System",
        "modifiedOn": 1528448883000,
        "year": 2017,
        "fileName": "file1.pdf",
    }, {
        "id": 97,
        "createdBy": "System",
        "createdOn": 1528448883000,
        "modifiedBy": "System",
        "modifiedOn": 1528448883000,
        "year": 2017,
        "fileName": "file3.pdf",
    }]
}
```

}

And i was constructing a table based on the data as below:

```
------------------------------------
category -  filename - created by
------------------------------------
2017        file1.pdf     Sasi
            file2.pdf     sambhu
            file3.pdf     Madhavan
------------------------------------
2018        file4.pdf 
             -
             -
------------------------------------
```

And following is my angular code

```
this._svc.getUploadedfiles(parseInt(this.id)).then((data: any) => {
                    if (data.response) {
                        if (data.response.uploadedFiles) {
                            if (data.response.uploadedFromTS.length > 0) {
                                this.tableList = data.response.uploadedFiles.concat(data.response.uploadedFromTS);
    }
    ...
```

How can I group my data in such a way that i can display them as shown in the table. Currently am just blindly displaying all the records. so year been duplicating in my first column. How can i group them to achieve it guys? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can do some modification to your raw data.

You can rearrange your data by **grouping** them (by year).

Some thing like this :

**e.g, this is your data**

```
let test =  [{
            "id": 97,
            "createdBy": "System",
            "createdOn": 1528448883000,
            "modifiedBy": "System",
            "modifiedOn": 1528448883000,
            "year": 2017,
            "fileName": "file2.pdf"},
        {
            "id": 97,
            "createdBy": "System",
            "createdOn": 1528448883000,
            "modifiedBy": "System",
            "modifiedOn": 1528448883000,
            "year": 2017,
            "fileName": null,
        },
        {
            "id": 97,
            "createdBy": "System",
            "createdOn": 1528448883000,
            "modifiedBy": "System",
            "modifiedOn": 1528448883000,
            "year": 2018,
            "fileName": "xwe",
        }
    ]
```

you can group it by year :

```
   let result = test.reduce(function (r, a) {
            r[a.year] = r[a.year] || [];
            r[a.year].push(a);
            return r;
        }, Object.create(null));
```

and you will get the result of your need!

[image]

Comment: my main doubt is i have to iterate through my each td all the time. Just wanna avoid that much of looping

Comment: you can do this type of grouping first, then you will have sorted data and you can bind directly to td. this can prevent looping on td